# Unknown PLC function block symbol

Tags: plc

I am currently writing a function description for a machine in our manufacturing production.

What does this star/sun-like symbol mean?

[image: Symbol]

Comment: maybe forced value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's actually a button. Clicking it adds additional inputs.
[image]